# configure the ngModel in a template of a directive, dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to setup the ngModel of all the fields in my form dynamically, I mean, every field got a name (a "@" scope variable), and depending on this name, I want to bind it to one or another property of the scope.

For example:

```
<my-input field="oneName"></my-input>
```

I would expect it to be replaced with:

```
<input name="oneName" ng-model="$scope.map.oneName"></input>
```

My problem comes when I try to configure the ng-model in the template, it only works if I either hard code it in the template, or I specify an extra "=" scope variable, which does not suit me.

I need somehow to configure the ngModel of the template at compile or link time.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: it should work then..what is problem? explain more please

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this directive? Note that the HTML is invalid, and that replace is deprecated.

Comment: Questions must include the desired behavior and a specific problem or error. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.